# Which Map does ArcGIS Online use for geocoding?

Tags: arcgis-online, geocoding

I would like to ask which Map provider does ArcGIS use for geocoding? My addresses are unstructured (with Floor #, Block #,...) but the precision is quite high when I manually check the locations in Google Maps.

Comment: By Map, I think you mean "which data source" provider?

Answer (score 0):

**Here** is the most common.
https://www.here.com/platform/location-based-services

source:
https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocode-coverage.htm

Level 1
The darkest-shaded countries in the map are Level 1. They **provide the highest quality geocoding experience**. Address searches are likely to result in accurate matches to PointAddress and StreetAddress levels.

Example:
Country Name    Supported Country Codes Supported Languages Supported Language Codes

```
Data Sources
Argentina

ARG, AR

Spanish

ES

HERE, Geonames

Australia

AUS, AU

English

EN

PSMA Australia, HERE, Geonames

Austria

AUT, AT

German, Croatian, Croatian Transliterated

DE, CR, EN

BEV, HERE, Geonames

Belgium

BEL, BE

Dutch, French, German

NL, FR, DE

HERE, Geonames

Brazil

BRA, BR

Portuguese

PT

HERE, Geonames

Canada

CAN, CA

English, French

EN, FR

HERE, Geonames
```